# Proper spaces with verbatim

Tags: spacing, verbatim

there is following code:

```
\begin{verbatim}
pc:~$ ls
folder1                Documents         folder2        New Folder  folder3
folder4444             Downloads         folder5        Pictures    Templats
\end{verbatim}
```

And the output is:

```
folder1             Documents       folder2       New Folder  folder3
folder4444             Downloads         folder5        Pictures    Templats
```

The thing is, that words in output are shifted. However when I use verbatim*, everything is all right, but there is ␣ character. It seems like spaces are not the same width as letters. How to output text with proper spaces? Or is there some other good method to print terminal output?

Edited:

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{report}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
pc:~$ ls
fffffff                Documents         gggggggggggg   New Folder  hhhhh
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj        eeeeeeeee         kkkk           Pictures    Templates
Desktop                xxxxx             ccccccccccccc  Public      dddddd
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  fffffffffeeeeeee  jjjjj          qqqqqqqqqq  sssww
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't see the problem in my testing. Can you provide a more complete example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output lines are too wide for the page. You will get warnings about overfull hboxes. I can see the shifting, but it goes away for example after making margins smaller for a quick test, so adjust font or line width.

Original example output:

[image: original output with shift]

With `\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}` warnings go away and it changes:

[image]